# Output Export in Mathematica

Tags: export

I have a command line that generates lists as output and is running in a loop, so generates, multiple long lists. Each list is to be exported as a .txt file. How can I automate the name generation of the output files. I intend to use the same name as the input file but with the .txt extension in output of course.

```
For[
  i = 1,i < 3,i++,
  outdata = ReadList[ test[[i]], Record, RecordSeparators -> {{">"},{" "}} ];
  Print[outdata]
  ]
```

How can I automate the export?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following should do:

```
For[i = 1, i < 3, i++, 
  outdata = ReadList[test[[i]], Record, RecordSeparators -> {{">"}, {" "}}];
  Export[FileBaseName[test[[i]]] <> IntegerString[3, 10, i] <> ".txt", outdata,"List"]
];
```

`FileBaseName` strips the file name in `test[[i]]` from its extension (if it has any). `IntegerString[3, 10, i]` generates strings of the form "001", "002", "003" etc. and <> (`StringJoin`) glues the substrings together.

There is a number of output formats you could use in `Export`. I chose "List" but you may want to examine [the BasicFormats guide page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/BasicFormats.html) for more.

Comment: Thank you, but i actually figured out another way!

Comment: For[i = 10, i < 20, i++,outdata =ReadList[test[[i]],  Record, RecordSeparators -> {{">"}, {" "}}]; 
 prin = "n" <> Riffle /@ (ToString /@ #) & /@ worklist[[i]] <> ".txt";
  Export[prin, outdata]]