# Generating list of labeled string

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I want to generate a table that gives the following output:

```
output: {"x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5"}
```

I have tried:

```
Table["x"*i, {i, 5}]
```

which gives

```
{"x", 2 "x", 3 "x", 4 "x", 5 "x"}
```

I wonder what is a correct way of doing this?

Comment: In mathematica, like in other languages (or very most of them), there is a clear distinction beetween integer (i) and string ("blabla"). If you multiply a string by a integer, you don't obtain a string. Hence your question sounds extra-terrest.

Comment: A bit of an extrapolation, but also check out [Indexed Variables](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html) for these things.

Comment: Some related: [(3165)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3165), [(21109)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21109), [(48315)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48315), [(60680)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60680), [(73135)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73135), [(118658)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118658).  See `StringTemplate[]` in addition to `ToString`.

Comment: Also related, or duplicate: [176419](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/176419/106), [36886](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36886/106), and see [How to print an integer with n leading zeros in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7419245/499167) on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Table["x" <> ToString[i], {i, 5}]
```

> {"x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5"}

Comment: That was clever, thank you loads gonna accept this :)